# What does z <- sort(x%*%y) do?

Tags: r, sorting, statistics

I am trying to understand a solution to a problem set posted by a the TA in a stats class, and he used the following commands to calculate the p-value in a problem:

```
FisherMeans <- sort(m1%*%Yobs)/NT # FisherMeans contains all possible outcomes.
```

Where `m1` is a matrix with all the possible assignment vectors, `Yobs` is a vector with the observed outcomes (each row in `m1` is as long as `Yobs`), and `NT` is the sample size (i.e. 1/2 the length of `Yobs`).

What is `sort(m1%*%Yobs)` doing? The TA says this is equivalent to doing the following, but I'm too new to R to understand how they're equivalent.

```
FisherMeans <- rep(NA,nrow(m1))
for (ii in 1:nrow(m1)) {
    FisherMeans[ii] <- mean(Yobs[m1[ii,]==1]) - mean(Yobs[m1[ii,]==-1])
}
```

Comment: Are exactly one half of the values in each row of `m1` 1 and the other half -1? If so, then `(m1 %*% Yobs)/NT` is equivalent to the code at the bottom. However, the top code is computing a sorted version, while the bottom code is not sorting. The reason this code is equivalent is actually a mathematical observation, not a coding observation. Write out a few rows of the matrix product `m1 %*% Yobs` and I think you'll see the equivalence.

Comment: `mean(Yobs[m1[ii,]==1])` means "The mean of the `Yobs` values in locations where there's a 1 in the `ii`th row of `m1`".

Comment: If you don't understand what something does break it down and look at what each step is doing. First type `?'%*%'` then take a look at what the output of each step is `head(m1%*%Yobs)` `head(sort(m1%*%Yobs))` `head(sort(m1%*%Yobs)/NT)`